# Understanding a find2perl result

Tags: perl, find

I have been working on a script that will recursive search a filesystem and delete any file (no directories) that is older than 20 days. I used the `find2perl` command (that is part of [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.24.1/ext/File-Find/lib/File/Find.pm)) and this was the result. (I noted that it didn't understand the `-delete` option, so I had to use the old `-exec...` option instead.)

(parts of the script truncated)

```
sub delete_old_files {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    (int(-M _) > 20) &&
    unlink($_);
}
```

I understand the `lstat` part, the `-f` file check, and the `unlink`, but I'm not sure how the `(int(-M _) > 20)` works. Obviously it is checking for modified date within 20 days, but I've never seen that syntax before, and curious to understand where it comes from and how it works. I'm also curious how it can reference the iterator as a plain underscore without using `$_` for the `-f` and the time check piece.

Comment: The `-x` operator should check to see if a file exists and is executable. That isn't the case here (at least shouldn't be).. many of these files are txt files that are not executable, and are included in the results of the command.

Comment: In Perl documentation, `-X` is used as a placeholder for filetest operators. E.g., see `perldoc -f -X`

Comment: Ah yes, I just read about those -- I've never seen nor used those before. Learn something new everyday... :)

Answer (score 5):

The results of the [lstat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html) call are cached. By using `_`, you avoid multiple lstat calls.

> Does the same thing as the stat function (***including setting the special `_` filehandle***) but stats a symbolic link instead of the file the symbolic link points to ... (*emphasis mine*)

From [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html):

> If `stat` is passed the special filehandle consisting of an underline, no `stat` is done, but the current contents of the `stat` structure from the last `stat`, `lstat`, or `filetest` are returned.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs for the -X functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

> -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.

The special filehandle `_` caches the last file stats, so any subsequent use of the `-X _` will use the cached values.

Comment: I also just found it, but got distracted so couldn't write it up. It's really nicely hidden.

Comment: So the reason its `_` and not `$_` is just because it's coming from `lstat`, is that right?

Comment: @TimS. yes, but more additional informations are [in this doc too](https://perldoc.perl.org/filetest.html)

Comment: @jm666 thanks -- very helpful. I've done tons of filetests in bash/sh, but hadn't had a lot of experience with them in perl. It explains a lot.

Comment: @TimS. yvw. Fortunately, the perl documentation is really excellent. (Just take much time to read thru all) :)

Comment: Yeah well, try grepping for an underscore in perldoc... :)

Comment: @simbabque Exactly.. some specific things are extremely difficult to search for in docs.

Comment: @TimS. if we disregard the actual perldoc, http://grep.cpan.me is a really nice tool for that kind of thing though.